# Error: modpost: "vfs_fstatat" undefined for kernl 5.10.113

Tags: linux, kernel, undefined

I've developed a kernel module, have been built on kernel version 4.9 and 5.4, and works file. But when I try to build for kernel version 5.10.113, I got following error:

```
ERROR: modpost: "vfs_fstatat" [/home/jarvisbao/***/build/kernel/shman/shman.ko] undefined!
```

I used vfs_stat function to in a function as below:

```
int file_stat(char *path, struct kstat *st){
    mm_segment_t oldfs;
    int ret=0;
#if LINUX_VERSION_CODE < KERNEL_VERSION(5,0,0)
    oldfs = get_fs();
    set_fs( get_ds() );
#elif LINUX_VERSION_CODE < KERNEL_VERSION(5,10,0)
    oldfs = get_fs();
    set_fs( KERNEL_DS );
#else
    oldfs = force_uaccess_begin();
#endif
    ret = vfs_stat(path, st);
#if LINUX_VERSION_CODE < KERNEL_VERSION(5,10,0)
    set_fs(oldfs);
#else
    force_uaccess_end(oldfs);
#endif
    return ret;
}
```

It seems there are some difference for calling vfs_stat between kernel version 5.10 and 5.4, but I don't know.

Comment: I develop kernel module on WSL2 (distribution is Ubunto 20.04), and installed linux-headers-5.11.0-22-generic through apt, and try to compile the module on it, but still have the same problem.

Comment: I also tried on native Ubuntu distribution(20.04), the problem still exists.

Comment: I looked into vfs_stat function declaration in linux/fs.h, it will call vfs_statx in 5.4, it will call vfs_fstatat in 5.10, but the compilation can not find vfs_fstatat.

Comment: It seems vfs_fstatat is missing from 5.10.113's Module.symvers

Comment: I removed file_stat function completetly to avoid such issue.

Answer (score 0):

Implementation of vfs_fstatat contains in fs/stat.c.
For success compilation you should add EXPORT_SYMBOL(vfs_fstatat) after them implementation.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).